# Pandas order error when sorting dataframe and removing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been using the following code:

```
UsersFullUnique = UsersFullLoc
UsersFullUnique.Placetype = UsersFullUnique.Placetype.astype('category', 
                                    categories=['Continent', 'Country', 'State', 'County','Town','POI', 'Suburb', 'LocalAdmin', 'Island', 'Estate', 'Colloquial', 'HistoricalTown', 'HistoricalCounty', 'LandFeature', 'Supername'], 
                                    ordered=True)

UsersFullUnique = UsersFullUnique.sort_values('Placetype').groupby('ID', as_index=False).first()
UsersFullUnique.head(8)
```

To sort the following dataframe:

```
ID          Unnamed: 0  WOE_ID  Locationname_x  Name_Type   Language_x  Username    Friends Followers   Status_count    Favorites   Account_age                     ISO Locationname    Language    Placetype   Parent_ID
100000045   3363940     2459115 New York City   V           ENG         UsersDude   35.0    10.0         0.0             0           Mon Dec 18 11:19:42 CST 2009   US  New York         ENG        Town        2347591
```

Which is giving me the error

```
TypeError: _astype() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ordered'
```

Now the odd thing is I used this bit of code on two other datasets with index

```
Unnamed: 0  WOE_ID  Locationname_x  Name_Type   Language_x  ID  Username    Friends Followers   Status_count    Favorites   Account_age ISO Locationname_y  Language_y  Placetype   Parent_ID
```

and

```
WOE_ID  ISO Locationname    Language    Placetype   Parent_ID   ID  Username    Friends Followers   Status_count    Favorites   Account_age
```

Which contained nearly the same type of information and it gave no errors.

Anyone know a possible solution?

Comment: You also call `.astype('category', ...)` on the other datasets?

Comment: Yes. The only difference in the code is the names of the two variables in   `UsersFullUnique = UsersFullLoc` and each mention of UsersFullUnique.

Comment: Could it be a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10696)? Try to reset it as string first, then set it as category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a bug similar to [this one](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10696). The immediate solution would be to make sure the column is not already a category:

```
if UsersFullUnique.Placetype.dtype != 'category': 
    UsersFullUnique.Placetype = UsersFullUnique.Placetype.astype('category', 
                                    categories=[...], 
                                    ordered=True)
```

The more general problem is that with `UsersFullUnique = UsersFullLoc` you do not make a copy but simply give two names to the same object, so any changes made on the new dataframe will also be made on the old one.

If for some reason you need a copy, you should use:

```
UsersFullUnique = UsersFullLoc.copy(deep=True)
```

Comment: Sorry, I had put the code to work after you answered but it takes a while to complete (large datasets) and have been busy the last two days. It works, thank you!